# How can I set a value after data binding, but before validation, in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I need to set a "time submitted" field on one of my domain objects. Validation rules require that property to be there, but I can't have it set by data binding from the form because then the user could change it. How can I set a property of the bound object (or about-to-be-bound object) before validation occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but you have 2 options to manipulate your data, on client side using Java Script, on server side using customer Validator.

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    /**
    * This Validator validates just Person instances
    */
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        p.setanyValue(some value); //changing object value
        if (p.getAge() < 0) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "negativevalue");
        } else if (p.getAge() > 110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe Stuff

I believe that binding starts by creating a new instance of a class.  Assuming that this is true, you could add a `blah = new Date();` in the constructor.  Although this would happen before binding, I believe it fulfills the core requirement of *get the submit time, but don't let the client edit it.*

If this is wrong, check out the `InitializingBean` interface (or the corresponding `init-method` bean attribute).

Looks like spring 3.0 has even more lifecycle options.  check out section *3.6.1.4 Combining lifecycle mechanisms* in the [Spring 3.0 Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

### Better Info

You should be able to register a handler interceptor and set the submit time therein.

Check out the *15.4.1 Intercepting requests - the HandlerInterceptor interface* section in the Spring 3.0 Reference (link is above).